# How to allow limited internet access to employees/children

Tags: webbrowser-control

I was wondering how I could set up a computer (windwos xp) or browser to allow access to only 2 or 3 websites?  I know where I currently work they have 'email stations' which are computers will access only to the company homepage and email login.  Please let me know any ideas you all have.

Thanks!

Comment: search on "web filter" or "parental control" software

Comment: Windows can not be locked down. Stop trying. It's like trying to stop the rain by building a house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is accomplished by using a proxy.  There are several free, open source proxies (such as squid and varnish), but it may be easier to look at some of the for-pay solutions for parental controls.  I looked at net nanny before for some customers, and they were happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

McAfee has some parental control software built in to its standard PC protection package.
It allows you pretty easy control over home much time can be spent online and what kind of sites can be accessed.

You can download a free trial on the website. Its worth a try.